# JgTreeGrid Expand nodes to certain level without using loaded:true

Tags: jqgrid

I am using a jqgrid as a treegrid to display a hierarchy. 
The data is pulled up from DB and I am constructing the hierarchy data based on parent-child relationship done on the serverside. 
One page load I have the load the tree upto x level (this is based on some user settings/preferences in the dB). 

So the user sees first few levels and then he clicks on a node to load more levels on-demand. 
 Problem: I cannot use "loaded:true" to expand the tree on load coz this will not enable me to load the rest of the levels on-demand.
I tried using the "expandRow" "expandNode", this expands the tree on the page load, but this gives me problem during the collapse. I cant collapse the tree nodes.

So what is the correct way for me to auto-expand the tree and show all nodes on page load and then allow the user to load remaining nodes on-demand.
code snippet:

```
gridComplete: function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                debugger;
                var ids = jQuery("#jqgTreeGrid").getDataIDs();
                for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                    rootNode = $("#jqgTreeGrid").jqGrid('getRowData')[i];
                    rootNode._id_ = rootNode.Id;
                    //rootNode.expanded = true;
                    $("#jqgTreeGrid").jqGrid('expandRow', rootNode);
                    $("#jqgTreeGrid").jqGrid('expandNode', rootNode);
                    //$("#" + rootNode._id_ + " div.treeclick")
                   // .removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e treeclick tree-plus")
                   // .addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s treeclick tree-minus");


                }
            }, 10);


        },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can use is `expanded` field which jqGrid is looking for in your data. Assuming that you are using [Adjacency Model](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadjacency_model) (although the general idea is the same for [Nested Set Model](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anested_set_model)) jqGrid is extending its reader to look for some more fields:

```
treeReader = {
   level_field: "level",
   parent_id_field: "parent",
   leaf_field: "isLeaf",
   expanded_field: "expanded"
}
```

You are most probably already using `level`, `parent` and `isLeaf` fields. The `expanded` field is optional, but if it is present and its value is `true` then jqGrid will autoexpand the node on load (and request for data if needed).

Comment: I already have expanded set to true on ALL the nodes, but i *think* this will not expand the tree in the current version.this might be an old thread :http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/treegrid/jqgrid-4-adjacency-model-expanded_field-problem/

Comment: You might be true, I have last time used this before 4.0. I will recheck that later and delete answer if true.

Comment: @anu So further investigation shows that this issue have been fixed in jqGrid source code on November 08 - the issue will no longer exists in next release (don't know when that is going to happen). At this point you can use grid.treegrid.js directly from [GitHub](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/tree/master/js)

Comment: thank you for the update. Can I use the js file before its official release?Just trying to understand the implications of using the code before its official release.

Comment: @anu It seems that since last offical release there where only two bug fixes in this file, so it should work with latest release. Just uncheck the checkbox next to TreeGrid on [jqGrid download page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6), download the file from GitHub and reference it after referencing the jqGrid script from your download.